# How do I make part of layer to disappear when it moves to certain part of the screen in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm currently using `CCScrollLayer` in cocos2d-x to scroll my list of items but I want the part of the list to disappear before it goes out of the screen.

I've tried transparent layer with higher z value but that didn't work since the layer was transparent and the list still shows up. I'm guessing I have to do something with `setPosition()` but just can't figure it out...

Any advices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe You need  GL_SCISSOR_TEST.

Try to override the layer draw() or visit() function with the following code

```
    void YOU_CLASS::visit()
    {
        glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        glScissor(x, y, width, height);   
        YOUR_PARENT_CLASS::visit();
        glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    }
```

and also,  add a line -lGLESv1_CM \ in Android.mk in your Classes Folder

it looks like below:

```
     LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(call host-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../android/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)) \
                     -lGLESv1_CM \
                     -lcocos2d -lcocosdenshion \
                     -L$(call host-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/libraries/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)) -lcurl
```